# Operation '&' is not defined for string and integer. For some reason it won't work

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim numbers(9) As Integer
Dim Card As String
Dim CardInfo As Integer
Const ListSize = 9

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    listOutput.Items.Clear()

    'populate the numbers array
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        numbers(i) = txtValue.Text
        Card = txtCard.Text

        CardInfo = numbers & Card
        listOutput.Items.Add(CardInfo)
    Next
    For i = 0 To ListSize
    Next i
    txtSearchValue.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  There is a difference between string and numbers, and a difference between arrays and strings.  If numbers is `{1,2,3,4,5}` and `Card` is say, "foo", what is the expected result from `numbers & Card`?

Comment: the out come that I would like to happen is foo would be allocated to 1 and the next name and number entered would joined the same way

Comment: So...you would get "foo1", "foo2", etc.? Just do `numbers & i.ToString()`

Comment: Is `Operation '&' is not defined for string and integer` an error message, or your own commentary on the problem at hand?

Comment: You say "allocated"... I think you man "concatenated". They are not at all the same thing, and getting this kind of thing right is _extremely_ important when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
numbers(i) = txtValue.Text
```

`Numbers` is an array of **integer** and `txtValue.Text`is a **String**.

You cannot save a String into an integer. My guess is that you want the value of that string. If its a "23" you want the number 23. For that you need to parse.

```
numbers(i) = Integer.Parse(txtValue.Text)
```

That will save the value of your string into the int.

**Important:**

If `txtValue` have a not valid text, something that's not a number it will throw an exeption. And we don't want that. So we can use TryParse:

```
Integer.TryParse(txtValue.Text,numbers(i))
```

If you are sure that it will always have a valid number on the txtValue, you can use the standart Parse, if not, use TryParse

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not complaining about a String + Integer. It's complaining about String + Integer(). The `numbers` variable used with the `&` operator in that code is an **array**, which doesn't just concatenate with strings. The subscript is missing.

But you can greatly reduce all that code anyway:

```
Const ListSize = 9   
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim items = Enumerable.Range(0, ListSize).Select(Function (i) String.Format("{0} {1}", txtCard.Text, i)).ToArray()
    listOutput.Items.Clear()
    listOutput.Items.AddRange(items)
    txtSearchValue.Focus()
End Sub
```